# System.ComponentModel.Component is a class but acts like a VB.NET module or an imported class (but isn't)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

How is it that properties like `System.ComponentModel.Component.DesignMode` are available without the fully-qualified name, i.e. just via `DesignMode` without the `Component` class?

I know of two ways to do this -- have `Component` be a module (VB.NET only) or import `Component` via `Imports` or `Using` directive.  Neither of these appears to be the case, though.  If you look at `System.ComponentModel.Component` in the object browser, it's a class, not a module, and I'm not importing that class anywhere (neither at the top of my class nor in the "Imported Namespaces" section of the "References" tab.

Related question: since modules don't exist in C#, what happens to my modules when they're compiled into IL such that their "module-ness" is maintained -- namely the ability to reference their members from anywhere?

Comment: No, they are **not**. Ask yourself: available **where**? In classes derived from Component (such as System.Windows.Forms.Control)?

Comment: `using` *directive*. There is a `using` *statement* in C#, and it's nothing to do with what you're talking about.

Comment: @Adriano -- You got it.  Momentary lapse on my part; for some reason I was forgetting that `System.Windows.Forms.Control` is derived from `System.ComponentModel.Component`.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, re: your related question, the vaguely similar concept in C# is [static classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx).

Comment: @Adriano -- If you post this as an answer, I'll accept yours.

Comment: Thank you but it was a hint more than an answer! If someone post something more detailed feel free to accept that! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably developing a `Control`. All `Control`s are `Component`s:

```
System.Object 
  System.MarshalByRefObject
    System.ComponentModel.Component
      System.Windows.Forms.Control
          {your control here}
```

And these methods are `protected` methods of `Component`, so are therefore available without any qualification inside your `Control` subclass.